# Proof for at least $n$ different prime factors in $2^{2^n}+2^{2^{n-1}}+1$ if $n$ is a natural number

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I am stuck on this proof and I need assistance please.
Not sure if it's the right start but here is what I've done so far:
I let $x=2^{n-1}$ and $2x=2^x$ that will change the expression to $2^{2x}+2^x+1$
than $y=2^x$ so the expression will be $y^2+y+1$ which is equal to $\frac{y^3-1}{y-1}$.
I am stuck there and don't know how to continue further or if this is the right approach.
Thank you for your assistance.

Oli.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in `$` signs.  `$2^2$` will show up as $2^2$